# How do I disable/enable checkboxlist items based on selected selection?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

Hi I am desperate for help, this post might look similar to previous post but however the approach and requirements for the code is totally different.

I have a checkbox list which the 2 checkboxlist items are populated using a stored procedure. However I added a "Select All" list item to the checkbox list.

**1.How can I disable all other checkbox list items when "Select All" is checked using javascript or C# onchanged event or jquery (but using external javascript file instead of putting in the aspx file itself)?**

AND

**2. How can I code to disable/enable certain checkbox items if a specific list item from check box 1 is checked using javascript or C# onchanged event or jquery (but using external javascript file instead of putting in the aspx file itself)?**

e.g in checkboxlist1 there is colours, food and drinks populated with the select all as well and in checkboxlist2 there is red, blue, green, chicken, spinach, coke and juice populated.

In 1st example scenario I checked colours and food so how can I code to only enable red, blue, green, chicken and spinach in checkboxlist2 OR in 2nd example scenario I checked only drinks in checkboxlist1 so it should only enable coke and juice which the rest of the list items should be disabled.

**3. How can I put my script in a js.file instead of in header as script without receiving $undefined error or runtime error where form1 id not found?**

ASPX

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<Script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var checked = false;
    $('#<%=Checkboxlist1.ClientID%> input:checkbox').click(function () {
        var currentIdone = 'Select All';
        var currentId = $(this).next().html();
        if (currentId == currentIdone) {

            if (checked) {

                $("#<%=Checkboxlist1.ClientID%> input").removeAttr('disabled');
                checked = false;
                return;
            }
            else {
                $("#<%=Checkboxlist1.ClientID%> input").attr('checked', false);
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
                $('#<%=Checkboxlist1.ClientID%> input:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                checked = true;
            }


        }

        });
    });

$(document).ready(function () {
    var checked = false;
    $('#<%=Checkboxlist2.ClientID%> input:checkbox').click(function () {
        var currentIdone = 'Select All';
        var currentId = $(this).next().html();
        if (currentId == currentIdone) {

            if (checked) {

                $("#<%=Checkboxlist2.ClientID%> input").removeAttr('disabled');
                checked = false;
                return;
            }
            else {
                $("#<%=Checkboxlist2.ClientID%> input").attr('checked', false);
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
                $('#<%=Checkboxlist2.ClientID%> input:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                checked = true;
            }


        }

        });
    });
</script> 
</head>

<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="Checkboxlist1" runat="server" Height="80px" Width="500px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value="Select All"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="Checkboxlist2" runat="server" Height="80px" Width="500px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select All" Value="Select All"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </form>    
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: We are also desperate to help you but you haven't posted your effort :P

Comment: Hi, no idea why code were not shown previously , but edited it. please take a look:)

Comment: Did you try passing the checkbox itself as a parameter to the external javascript method?

Comment: @newtoasp you mean when selecting **selectall** in `Checkboxlist1` should disable all items in `checkboxlist1` only right?

Comment: @john paul, yest I did link it to external java script but its returns me error

Comment: @Webruster I manually added a "Select All" list item thus when user check the select all item, the rest of the list items in checkboxlist 1 populated by the stored procedure will be disabled

Answer (score 0):

On `checkboxlist1_SelectedIndexChanged` i am assuming `Sellect all` value as `1` here is the code

```
 protected void checkboxlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string roles = "";
        try
        {
            roles = checkboxlist1.SelectedValue;



                foreach (ListItem li1 in this.checkboxlist1.Items)
                {
                    //checkboxlist1.Items.FindByText(li.ToString()).Selected = true;

                    if (li1.Value != "1" )
                    {
                           checkboxlist1.Items.FindByText(li1.ToString()).Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkboxlist1.Items.FindByText(li1.ToString()).Enabled = true;
                    }
                }



            Boolean A = false;
            foreach (ListItem li in this.checkboxlist1.Items)
            {
                //checkboxlist1.Items.FindByText(li.ToString()).Selected = true;

                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    A = true;
                }
            }
            if (A == false)
            {
                foreach (ListItem li in this.checkboxlist1.Items)
                {
                    checkboxlist1.Items.FindByText(li.ToString()).Enabled = true;
                }
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ClientLogger.ClientErrorLogger(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```